# Split Flags into Normalized Table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I have a table that looks like

```
OldThing
id  | Value    | Flags | ...
int | varchar  | int   | ...
... | ...      |   2   | ...
... | ...      |  19   | ...
... | ...      |  82   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
... | ...      |  19   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
... | ...      |  18   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
... | ...      |  55   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      | 112   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
... | ...      |  48   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      |  16   | ...
... | ...      |  64   | ...
... | ...      |  -1   | ...
... | ...      |   3   | ...
```

where `OldThing.Flags` is checked and generated in the application as a bitwise and of constant values defined in app.

I'm trying to move to an improved, more normalized database, with the following three tables:

```
Thing
id  | Value   | ...
int | varchar |

FlagDetail        
id  | description | mask
int | varchar     | int

Flag
ThingID | FlagID 
int     | int
```

I tried to generate the values for the FlagDetail table using `Join` with a custom `IEqualityComparer`, but it was returning very few of the results I wanted:

```
void Main()
{
    var flags = OldThings
           .ToArray()
           .Join(FlagDetails, thing=>thing.Flags.Value, 
                flag => flag.Mask, (t,f) => new {t, f}, 
                new BitwiseComparer())
           .Select (r => new Flag{ThingID = r.t.Id, FlagId = r.f.Id});

    Flags.InsertOnSubmit(flags);
    SubmitChanges();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class BitwiseComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
{
    public bool Equals(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a&b)>0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int n)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This resulted in 19 results, whereas the expected row count should be 29 (calculated by `SubscriptionTypes.Sum(st => EmailNames.Count(n => (n.Subscriptions & st.Mask)>0));`).

In the end, I resorted to using two nested `foreach` loops:

```
var flags = new List<Flag>();

foreach (var thing in OldThings)
{
    foreach (var flag in FlagDetails)
    {
        if ((thing.Flag & flag.Mask) > 0)
            subs.Add(new Flag{ThingId = Thing.Id, FlagId = flag.Id});
    }
}

Flags.InsertAllOnSubmit(flags);
SubmitChanges();
```

These tables are used in multiple applications, so migration will be gradual with additional `FlagDetail` rows added as we go.

Is there a way to generate the `flags` values in Linq, without having to manually write the loops?  I'm after something that I can quick and easily type up and run in LinqPad while migrating each app.

I currently have `FlagDetail` rows with Mask values of `1`, `2` and `4`.

Comment: Not sure i understand you well, but... Do you want to join `OldThings` with `FlagDetails`? Am i right? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to generate the rows for the `Flag` table, using the values of `FlagDetail.Mask`, so generate a `Flag` row when `(OldThing.Flags & FlagDetail.Mask) > 0`.  I'm just wondering if there's a way to do this in Linq that I'm missing.

Comment: @MaciejLos edited to include previous attempt.

Comment: can you give us the OldThings flags column content and the new flag-mask column content? no need for id or text

Comment: @Fredou Qusetion edited to include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless I misunderstood, what you need to do is a cross join and not a normal join

like this;

```
var flags = from o in OldThings.ToArray()
            from f in FlagDetails
            where (o.Flags.Value & flag.Mask) > 0
            select new Flag{ThingID = o.Id, FlagId = f.Id};
```

let say you have 3 rows in the `OldThings`;

> 1, 'blah1', 1
>     2, 'blah2', 2
>     3, 'blah3', 3

and 2 row in `FlagDetails`;

> 1, 'mask1', 1
>     2, 'mask2', 2

your join will give you this, the `Flag`;

> 1, 1
>   2, 2
>   3, 1

with my query you will have

> 1, 1
>   2, 2
>   3, 1
>   3, 2